# Fast MYSQL Query to remove Duplicates

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table with 100,000 rows and would like to remove all the duplicates. I have tried the following query already:

```
DELETE t1 FROM wt_tweets t1, wt_tweets t2 WHERE t1.ID < t2.ID AND t1.tweet_id = t2.tweet_id OR t1.tweet_user_id = t2.tweet_user_id
```

Unfortunately, it is quite slow. So I was wondering whether there is a faster alternative.

Comment: Please show examples of what duplicates are.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the existing query will always delete _all_ tweets, so I think you need a more detailed description of what you're trying to actually do.

Comment: I don't use mysql that often. I just noted that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is parsed like this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM wt_tweets t1, wt_tweets t2
    WHERE (t1.ID < t2.ID AND t1.tweet_id = t2.tweet_id) OR
          (t1.tweet_user_id = t2.tweet_user_id)
```

Under the circumstances, this will delete all rows (assuming `tweet_user_id` is not `null`).  So, a faster method is:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE wt_tweets;
```

However, I doubt that is your intention.

If you wanted to delete rows where the `tweet_id` is the same (but keeping the one with the largest id):

```
DELETE t
    FROM wt_tweets t LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT tweet_id, MAX(ID) as maxId
          FROM wt_tweets 
          GROUP BY tweet_id
         ) tt
         ON t.tweet_id = tt.tweet_id AND t.id = tt.maxId
    WHERE tt.tweet_id IS NULL;
```